# Defining variables in yaml for azure devops pipeline using key-value pairs and by using variable specifier

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I am new to YAML and am trying to create a simple yaml file for an azure devops pipeline.

In the following I define the variables using key-value pairs and it works

```
variables:
  var2: varVal2

trigger:
- master

pool:
  name: 'azure pipelines'
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- script: echo $(var2)
```

In the following this time, I define the variables using variable specifier syntax and it works fine again. The msdn reference is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#specifying-variables)

```
variables:
  -name: var3
  value: varVal3

trigger:
- master

pool:
  name: 'azure pipelines'
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- script: echo $(var3)
```

Now when I try to use both the key-value pairs syntax and by using variable specifier, it would not work. What am I missing? The following does not work.

```
variables:
  -name: var3
  value: varVal3
  var4:varVal4

trigger:
- master

pool:
  name: 'azure pipelines'
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- script: echo $(var3)
- script: echo $(var4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As the [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#specifying-variables) describes variable specifier is another syntax, useful when you want to use variable templates or variable groups. In this alternate syntax, the variables keyword takes a list of variable specifiers. The variable specifies are name for a regular variable, group for a variable group, and template to include a variable template

Above document says variable specifier works as an alternate syntax when you want to use variable templates or variable groups. Though the document doesnot say the two syntaxes are not compatible, after testing we found that the build yaml definition would bark errors if they appeared together.

To define variables using key-value pairs is very convenient and it is suggested to use this syntax unless you want use variable templates or variable groups.

If you want enable this feature in yaml definition. You can [submit a feature suggest](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) to Microsoft development team. Hopefully they will consider implementing this feature in the future.

Click Suggest a feature -> Choose Azure Devops
[image]